# How can I update my XAML while a database operation is ongoing and then update it again after it's finished?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My intention is that when a button is pressed an activity indicator will display on the screen immediately and then a database query will happen. Once the query is completed a XAML grid is created, the activity indicator will be removed and the new XAML grid added. In practice this is all working but often the activity indicator does not show so I am wondering if I have the way I coded this wrong.

I have a button that causes an UpdateDetails method to fire:

```
    private async Task UpdateDetails()
    {
        details.Children.Clear();
        details.Children.Add(Helpers.Activity.Create());

        var newGrid = doLongRunningDatabaseTaskandCreateXAML();

        details.Children.Clear();
        details.Children.Add(Helpers.Activity.Create(newGrid);
    }
```

How I can make the activity indicator display first until the database operation has completed and then have the newGrid appear? Note that what's most important is for the activity indicator to show while the database operation and creation of newGrid is ongoing.

Comment: `async` and `await`, you are not await your long running code

Comment: If I await that code then will the 2nd line still update the UI? Can you give me an example of how I can do this. Note that the doLongRunningDatabaseTaskandCreateXAML(); isn't ASYNC.  Will I have to change that?

Comment: I don't see how deleting your question and asking again is helping. You just lost all progress that has been made and comments by people who put effort into this.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis can you link the (deleted) question

Comment: There was I believe just the one comment and I didn't understand fully what was explained. So I tried to go back to basics with this question and explain my question more clearly.

Comment: No, he deleted it and posted it again to be on top of the list again

Comment: Also note that I did respond to the one comment and ask for more clarification from the commentor but after waiting an hour there was no reply so I assumed that the person may not see my response.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Now that I saw your comment even I remember seeing his earlier post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its simple:

- Make your method synchronous
- Add the code that you don't want on UI thread in an async `Task.Run`

  ```
     Task.Run(async () =>
              {
                 //Your piece of code 
              }
  ```
- Now when you want to update the UI just write that part of the code in `MainThread` using the following

  ```
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { //UI updation });
  ```

### Update

Your code should look something like this:

```
 private async Task UpdateDetails()
{      
       Task.Run(async () =>
        {
         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { details.Children.Clear();
         details.Children.Add(Helpers.Activity.Create());});

         var newGrid = await doLongRunningDatabaseTaskandCreateXAML();

         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {  details.Children.Clear();
         details.Children.Add(Helpers.Activity.Create(newGrid);});  
       }     
}
```

**Note** that if `doLongRunningDatabaseTaskandCreateXAML` is of the type `async task` then you do not need to use the `Task.Run` method at all.

Comment: Can you add the code from my question into your answer just to make it really clear. I had an answer to a similar question before but it was a little unclear and I think the most clear would be to use the original code as it's not very big in the answer.  Thank you

Comment: I have updated the answer as per my understanding of your code kindly take a look @Alan2

Comment: You could omit the `Task.Run` call altogether. Assuming `doLongRunning...()` is of type `Task<T>`, the `await` should automatically place it in a non-UI task.

Comment: @Tom Agreed But since we do not know its better to add it this way for a better understanding of the questioner!!